# Is there a date time tag in KepserverEX 6?

Tags: plc, opc-ua, kepserverex

I am looking for a tag in KepServerEX 6 to get the current system date and time, these tags could be used for further usages such as PLC date time updates.

The time must be separated into simple HH and MM tags.

I have searched in the simulator and advanced simulator tags but nothing found.

Any help appreciated

Comment: The client would not have built-in tags.  I don't think the KEPServer simulator does either.  Are you looking for any OPC UA server that provides this or do you need to have it in KEPServerEX simulator?

Comment: @eglease I have the same idea about KEPServerEX. I need an OPC UA server that can do the following jobs: 1. Read/Write PLC tags with proper divers for various PLC manufacturers 2. Able to connect to .Net apps(with OPC.net nuget package) 3. Log Tags to SQL database based on conditions  4. Adjust date time in PLC. 5. Log alarm and events in a database. No matter about the KEPServerEX or any other ones.

Comment: For your situation, 1.  Kepware, Softing, Matrikon, maybe a few other have various PLC drivers for different protocols.  2.  Are you looking to develop something yourself or can you buy a turn-key SCADA system?  3.  There are a number of products that connect directly to SQL including Softing, Matrikon, and Integration Objects.  4.  This would depend on the properties of the PLC.  Some have their own built-in OPC server, others may not have a time tag to adjust.  5.  See 3.

Comment: Also look at SoftwareToolbox TopServer.

Comment: to get more info, in 1. I have used kepware and it's OK 2. I have developed 2 apps, one is a .net razor app and the other a UWP app. both of them connect to KepServerEX and manage tags(read/write) with OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.UA.Client package from nuget. 3. There is a data logger plug-in in kepServerEx also which logs tag values to SQL DB and it's not bad(only some special triggers are not possible) 4. I think for this one may be a good idea to program a C# function in my apps to get straight to what I need to be change in PLC.

Comment: 5. KepServerEx has an AE plugin but AE is not possible to log in DB in data logger in Kepware also I didn't find a way to connect it to my UWP/razor apps . Do you have any recommendations about how to connect opc alarm and events to C#?

Comment: AE and HD are built-into OPC UA but I never used them.  You can try a commercial SDK like Unified Automation.  I know it supports both data formats.

Answer (score 0):

For that you could mount a local mqtt broker that retrieves the srtructre of mqtt like:

```
Links example:
>http://localhost/webservices/home/GETSERVERTIME+Hour
> http://localhost/webservices/home/GETSERVERTIME+Minutes
> http://localhost/webservices/home/GETSERVERTIME+Seconds
```

mount a mqtt client on your kepserverex
[image: Response Should look like this]
Maybe Using c# could be more easy to you:
[C# .net guide](https://blog.behroozbc.ir/basic-mqtt-broker-with-c-sharp)

Also you can mount a Modbus master on your windows and retrive the info you need with modbus tcp/ip client, i think this is easiest way:
[Mosbus master and slave c# .net](https://techitmore.com/dotnet/modbus-tcp-communication-in-net-c/)

Answer (score 0):

With an OPC-Ua client, exploring the KepwareEX 6 opc-ua server tags (in my case namespace is 2) there are:

`ns=2;s=_System._Time`
`ns=2;s=_System._Time_Hour`
`ns=2;s=_System._Time_Hour24`
`ns=2;s=_System._Time_Minute`

You can cast them (the last 3 tag that are numbers) in strings using a derived advanced tag.  I not found the solution to preserve the 2 char format   (01:01 become 1:1)

Alternatively you can use the HH:MM:SS _System._Time string directly that respect the format.